# How do you use an inner join and a subquery in a SelectById proc?

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures, subquery, ssms

So my directions are to select from 3 tables. Everything is linked to the primary keys except Images is linked to PrimaryImageId as a foreign key.

I am supposed to select from Images table and use a subquery for the Skills.

Not sure how to join Images Table so I can get the columns in to select.

[Image to my diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cxvx.png)

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Friends_SelectByIdV3]
    @Id int
as


/* ------ Test Code --------

DECLARE @id int = 1;

EXECUTE [dbo].[Friends_SelectByIdV3] @id


*/



Begin 

    SELECT f.Id
            ,i.Url
            ,i.Id
            ,i.TypeId
          ,f.Title
          ,f.Bio
          ,f.Summary
          ,f.Headline
          ,f.Slug
          ,f.StatusId
           ,f.DateModified
          ,f.DateCreated
          ,f.UserId
          ,Skills = (
                    select s.id as skillId
                            ,s.Name as name
                    from dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills as fs
                    on fs.SkillId = s.Id
                    Where fs.FriendId = f.Id
                    FOR JSON AUTO
                        )
         from dbo.FriendsV2 as f 
        Where EXISTS(
            select 1
             from dbo.Images as i
             where i.Id = f.PrimaryImageId
             --select 1
             --from dbo.Images as i
             --where i.Id = f.PrimaryImageId
             )
        order by f.Id
End
```

Comment: there might be multiple `SkillId` per friend. How do you want to return the `SkillId` ?

Comment: @Squirrel The skill does have multiple. They didnt specify. Just as long as it return at the moment. Im not sure how to join the image with all the stuff i have already.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured where I went wrong. Looks like I didnt need the where exist. I just had to inner join below the subquery.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Friends_SelectByIdV3]
    @Id int
as


/* ------ Test Code --------

DECLARE @id int = 5;

EXECUTE [dbo].[Friends_SelectByIdV3] @id


*/



Begin 


    

    SELECT f.Id
            ,i.[Url]
            ,i.Id
            ,i.TypeId
          ,f.Title
          ,f.Bio
          ,f.Summary
          ,f.Headline
          ,f.Slug
          ,f.StatusId
           ,f.DateModified
          ,f.DateCreated
          ,f.UserId
          ,Skills = (
                    select s.id as skillId
                            ,s.[Name] as name
                    from dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills as fs
                    on fs.SkillId = s.Id
                    Where fs.FriendId = f.Id
                    FOR JSON AUTO
                        )
         from dbo.FriendsV2 as f inner join dbo.Images as i
            on f.PrimaryImageId = i.Id
        --Where EXISTS(
        --  select 1
        --   from dbo.Skills as s inner join dbo.FriendSkills as fs
        --   on fs.SkillId = s.Id
        --   where s.Id = fs.SkillId
        --   --select 1
        --   --from dbo.Images as i
        --   --where i.Id = f.PrimaryImageId
        --   )
        where @id = f.Id
        order by f.Id
        
End
```